# Modifying CDN Migration Paths

Tags: amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to migrate a CDN from rackspace to aws.

In the former, everything is mapped to individual containers via CNAME records like so:

```
container1  =   CNAME   =   container1.cdndomain
container2  =   CNAME   =   container2.cdndomain
container3  =   CNAME   =   container3.cdndomain
```

When we set up aws, everything I read said to set up one (only) cloudfront, with various buckets.  So that's what I did.

Now I'm trying to somehow remap all of those containers into their new aws home and corresponding 'buckets' but the single cloudfront is making it hard for me.

I'd rather not go through thousands of line of code and config files and change all the current urls (e.g. manually change container1.cdndomain to cdndomain/container1).

But I can't find a way to remap

```
this:  http://bgimgs.cdndomain/image
```

To it's aws counterpart

```
here:   http://cdndomain/bucket/image
```

We use Zerigo for DNS and the interface will accept this CNAME path:

```
container.domain  =  CNAME = cdndomain/bucket
```

but aws doesn't route that to the correct bucket.

I've tried an .htaccess solution

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^container1\.cdndomain(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:\/\/cdndomain/container1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But that's not working either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the advice came from to only use one CloudFront distribution with multiple S3 buckets.  Sure, you *can*, but if it doesn't match your needs, there is no reason why you *should*.

Just create multiple distributions.

If you are already accessing them with different hostnames, they they're different collections of objects, I can't actually think of any reason such advice would be applicable in your case.  The only reason that comes to mind that would suggest you use just one CloudFront distro with multiple buckets would be to store all the content (from the different buckets) behind one hostname, or behind multiple hostnames *with the same paths* used at each hostname (a hack to get browsers to load assets faster is to convince the browser that the assets are all coming from different hosts, so more parallel connections will be opened by the browser).

In your case, this doesn't seem like what you need at all.  Distributions, themselves, are free.  Problem solved.

Regarding DNS, the other vendor may *accept* that configuration, but that doesn't mean it's a *valid* configuration.  It isn't.  You can't change paths with DNS.

Regarding `.htaccess`, S3 doesn't process `.htaccess` files.  If you were creating them on your web server, that would be a no-go, too, since the web server would not see the requests in order to redirect them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Michael.  You're right about the DNS.  It wasn't actually routing the /*.  I did set up a domain at cdndomain so I have total ability to define an .htaccess at the domain.  Still haven't found a solution other than just rewriting all links or setting up a bunch of cloudfronts.  Those may just be the only ways.

Comment: Based on what you already have in place, I don't see another straightforward, uncomplicated, resilient solution... but I not only see no problem with creating multiple cloudfront distributions, I see no notable advantage in trying to avoid it, since your existing code is already accessing different hostnames.

Comment: Of course, it would be easily done with HAProxy on EC2 in the same region as your S3 buckets, configured as a Cloudfront Custom Origin (then relaying to the buckets) since HAProxy allows destination route selection *and* URL rewriting based on `Host:` header, which Cloudfront can be configured to forward to the custom origin.  Increased flexibility comes at the cost of increased complexity, of course.  But this is a solution I use in some scenarios to rewrite paths or choose buckets on the way to S3.  (EC2/S3 traffic within a region is free, so there's no cost for the traffic).